# Home automation dialogues

Tags: alexa, google-assistant

Is there an available dataset from home automation conversational agent vendors such as Amazon-Alexa or Google Home.

I want a dataset where there are dialogues and knowledge bases of IoT devices similar to the [bAbI dataset](https://fb-public.app.box.com/s/chnq60iivzv5uckpvj2n2vijlyepze6w).

The dataset would have a dialogue between the human and the agent wherein the end the agent would fulfil the human's desires, such as open the kitchen light.

Answer (score 2):

I received answers from Google and Amazon. The former one said no and the latter one said at some point in the future. There is also an article about it on [venturebeat](https://venturebeat.com/2019/04/01/alexa-data-set-conversational-amazon/).